# Mac OS: can't install Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

have Mac OS Catalina (10.15.4) and can't install Eclipse. When I´ve downloaded Eclipse and try to install, it tells me:

> Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine.

But I can install every JDK, no one will satisfy Eclipse.

Comment: On macOS the current Java 14 has a bug, that prevents Eclipse to start. You have to uninstall Java 14 and install an older Java version (or wait until next Java 14 update is released).

Comment: @howlger For Oracle Java the 14.0.1 update is already available and does work.